# What's the difference between the various stochastic-blah tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have several tags named (stochastic-blah), what are the differences between:

- [stochastic-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-calculus)
- [stochastic-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-analysis)
- [stochastic-integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-integrals)
- [stochastic-processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-processes)

I have a feeling that there are certain degrees of overlaps here, and while I can see some differences, do we really need all four of the tags? Before we decide, it would be nice to know what each of the four tags are supposed to mean.

Comment: Very roughly speaking, I would say $\text{stochastic integrals } \subset \text{stochastic-calculus } \subset \text{stochastic processes } \subset \text{stochastic analysis}$. But, I'm sure others may find that overly crude. I would be most in favor of merging `stochastic-integrals` with `stochastic-calculus` with the other two left alone.

Comment: I think that the tagging is a stochastic process... you should post a question about it on the main site and tag it under [random]! :-)

Comment: [tag:stochastic-processes] is definitely a broader category than the rest; for example, finite state Markov chains are a very commonly encountered class of stochastic processes, but have little to do with stochastic analysis or integrals. The only one I'm not quite sure about is stochastic analysis -- Wikipedia [seems to consider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_analysis) it a synonym for stochastic calculus.

Comment: Stochastic Calculus = Mathematical Finance = \$\$ while Stochastic Analysis = Analyis = sadface

Comment: I came across the same issue recently. Shall we merge [tag:stochastic-integrals] into [tag:stochastic-calculus] and [tag:stochastic-analysis] into [tag:stochastic-processes]? I would say, that former joint tag would focus on the theory and practical examples of Ito integration w.r.t. general semimartingales and related issues, whereas the latter tag will be the general one for stochastic processes which includes e.g. [tag:markov-chains] and [tag:markov-processes]. Btw, since we don't have much of Markov stuff, perhaps we shall also merge the latter two together.