# Meta-Meta question: Duplicate for previous question without actual real answer

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, meta

So I was perusing the meta site, and I came across this closed link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20285/why-do-we-have-a-tag-called-stochastic-analysis

The reason it was closed was it was listed as a duplicate of [What's the difference between the various stochastic-blah tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3805/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-stochastic-blah-tags)

The things I find curious/interesting about this is the phrasing of the closing message for duplicates:
"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question."

It does not appear to me in any way that the old thread, question, which is back from 2012 actually has an answer! There's certainly no official "answer" given, and only 4 comments discussing it....seems far more like an open issue.   Since the original question is so old, what is the appropriate thing to do?

(note: I know nothing about any of the stochastic subjects and have no particular opinion on the actual question itself, I just found it strange to have something marked as 'answered' and then the original question didn't seem like that at all)

Comment: Wouldn't it be deliciously ironic if this is a duplicate as well? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila *grin* I was just amused that there actually was a meta tag, and the explanation made me go all Godel, Escher, Bach for a moment.  (It's metas, all the way down!)

Comment: Related post on meta.SE: [Meta duplicates don't require an answer. Don't suggest there is one when that's not true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/meta-duplicates-dont-require-an-answer-dont-suggest-there-is-one-when-thats)

Comment: @Alan Just don't ask questions about the [tag:meta] tag, or we'll have to make a [tag:meta-meta] tag. :P

Comment: Am I asking a meta-meta-meta question now?

Comment: Sadly, there's no actual ANSWER to this question...grr! :)

Answer (score -2):

I think that you should get someone to answer the old question.

I don't know if this is possible, but try to un-close the new question if nobody answers.